# How to check for null on an object and then move on if it is NULL?

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

In Java, what is the best way to check if an object has value or is returning `null`? Most examples I have found are not very good. Basically I have this code:

```
mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(reAuthTokens);
System.out.println(reAuthTokens);
if(reAuthTokens.equals(null)) {
    mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(Main.this);
    Log.e(TAG, "Keys not set -- I'm starting authentication");
}
```

I'm trying to get `reAuthTokens` to be checked for value and if it has none, move on and authenticate. However, I just get a `NullPointerException` on the if statement line. Is there something I can do better?

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_**OnCreate for rcook****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //AccessTokenPair tokens=null;      
    //AccessTokenPair tokens = getStoredKeys();   
    //System.out.println(access + "here I am"); 
    //clearKeys();
    //Log.e(TAG, "keys cleared");


    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
    AccessTokenPair reAuthTokens = new AccessTokenPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(reAuthTokens);

        System.out.println(reAuthTokens);

    if(reAuthTokens == null) {       
    mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(Main.this);
    Log.e(TAG, "Keys not set -- I'm starting authentication");



    }


//



    /*read settings*/
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean hide = mSettings.getBoolean(PREFS_HIDDEN, false);
    boolean thumb = mSettings.getBoolean(PREFS_THUMBNAIL, true);
    int space = mSettings.getInt(PREFS_STORAGE, View.VISIBLE);
    int color = mSettings.getInt(PREFS_COLOR, -1);
    int sort = mSettings.getInt(PREFS_SORT, 3);



    mFileMag = new FileManager();
    mFileMag.setShowHiddenFiles(true);
    mFileMag.setSortType(sort);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        mHandler = new EventHandler(Main.this, mFileMag, savedInstanceState.getString("location"));
    else
        mHandler = new EventHandler(Main.this, mFileMag);

    mHandler.setTextColor(color);
    mHandler.setShowThumbnails(thumb);
    mTable = mHandler.new TableRow();

    /*sets the ListAdapter for our ListActivity and
     *gives our EventHandler class the same adapter
     */
    mHandler.setListAdapter(mTable);
    setListAdapter(mTable);

    /* register context menu for our list view */
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    mStorageLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.storage_label);
    mDetailLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detail_label);
    mPathLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path_label);
    mPathLabel.setText("path: /sdcard");

    updateStorageLabel();
    mStorageLabel.setVisibility(space);

    mHandler.setUpdateLabels(mPathLabel, mDetailLabel);

    /* setup buttons */
    int[] img_button_id = {R.id.help_button, R.id.home_button, 
                           R.id.back_button, R.id.info_button, 
                           R.id.manage_button, R.id.multiselect_button,
                           R.id.dropbox_button
                           };

    int[] button_id = {R.id.hidden_copy, R.id.hidden_attach,
                       R.id.hidden_delete, R.id.hidden_move};

    ImageButton[] bimg = new ImageButton[img_button_id.length];

    Button[] bt = new Button[button_id.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < img_button_id.length; i++) {
        bimg[i] = (ImageButton)findViewById(img_button_id[i]);
        bimg[i].setOnClickListener(mHandler);

        if(i < 4) {
            bt[i] = (Button)findViewById(button_id[i]);
            bt[i].setOnClickListener(mHandler);
        }
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)) {
        bimg[5].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mReturnIntent = true;

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET)) {
        Log.e("MAIN", "Widget action, string = " + intent.getExtras().getString("folder"));
        mHandler.updateDirectory(mFileMag.getNextDir(intent.getExtras().getString("folder"), true));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `if (reAuthTokens == null))` instead. You're not trying to compare contents of objects; you're trying to compare references. "is `reAuthTokens` points to the same address as `null`?"

**EDIT** following updates from OP: `reAuthTokens` is of type `AccessTokenPair` (and I'm betting many readers initially thought this to be a `List`... I know I did). It is instantiated in this line:

```
AccessTokenPair reAuthTokens = new AccessTokenPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
```

Which is why the following condition will always be false: `reAuthTokens == null`. That's why, when coding `if (reAuthTokens == null)`, you get a "dead code" warning: the compiler knows that this condition can never be true, as you instantiate `reAuthTokens` a few lines above.

So, the type of comparison you're after is not about reference, but about content. You want to check whether `reAuthTokens` is "empty". But that doesn't make sense from the code you had quoted. How come you instantiate the object, and then want to check if it's "empty"?

I think your logic isn't right. You should first obtain the access token pair from where you expect it to be (the session?), and compare the result to `null`. Something like this:

```
AccessTokenPair reAuthTokens = mDBApi.getSession().getAccessTokenPair();

if (reAuthTokens == null) {
    reAuthTokens = new AccessTokenPair(...);
    mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(reAuthTokens);
}
```

Comment: See I tried that, but Eclipse reports the code in the statement as "dead code" if I do it that way. I know reAuthTokens has value too.

Comment: @SteveWeaver Are you sure? Please check again if you assigned a value to `reAuthTokens` before comparing it to `null`.

Comment: Yep positive...Its spits it right out in LogCat from the System.out.println(reAuthTokens); -- Its value is {key="uhvcudhc8r8f", secret="ufur8u8r9euf4"}

Comment: Oh. Another possibility: what class is your `reAuthTokens`? what type of object is it? use "System.out.println(reAuthTokens.getClass().getName()).

Comment: Its an AccessTokenPair

`AccessTokenPair reAuthTokens = new AccessTokenPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);`

Comment: Added the entire onCreate method for rcook. @Issac -- empty would be fine. Im just trying to say "Are the keys there? If not, we need to authenticate". Which for god's sake should be easy enough but it hasnt been.

Comment: Oh. It's all clear now (well, mostly). I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: All yours, hope that helps.

Comment: It helps a great deal. Thank you Isaac. I agree with you. I think my logic is flawed (Definitely not the first time...but hey Im learning). I need to rethink how I am doing this. Thank you again for the fast responses!